# Why the local reciprocity map $rec:F_\mathfrak{p}^* \rightarrow Gal(H_{\mathfrak{f}\mathfrak{p}}/H)$ is surjective?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Here $\mathfrak{f}$ is an ideal of $F$ relatively prime to $\mathfrak{p}$ and the extension $F\subset H \subset H_{\mathfrak{f}\mathfrak{p}}$ is such that $H$ is the maximal abelian extension such that the prime $\mathfrak{p}$ splits in $F$. $H_{\mathfrak{f}\mathfrak{p}}$ is the narrow ray class field of conductor $\mathfrak{f}\mathfrak{p}$. I'm referring to [pag.17, after the proof] https://www.math.harvard.edu/media/miller.pdf.

Comment: If I’m not mistaken (which I may well be), the reciprocity map $F_{\mathfrak{p}}^{\times} \rightarrow G_{F_{\mathfrak{p}}}^{ab}$ has dense image (in particular is onto every finite quotient) and $F_{\mathfrak{p}}=H_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Next, you need for $\mathfrak{p}$ in $H_{\mathfrak{fp}}/H_{\mathfrak{p}}$ to not split at all (aka $r=1$) so that the global Galois group is isomorphic to the local Galois group. This should be taken care of by the hypothesis on $H$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer: I have only two questions : 1-why the hypotheses on $\mathfrak{p}$ implies the iso between the Galois groups? 2- why the reciprocity map has the properties that you wroted?

Comment: Ok I find the solution to my answers, thank you so much!